# Venn diagram and equation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

How do I write an equation representing the green area?

G = (G ∪ R) ∪ (G ∩ D) ∪ (G ∩ U)

Is this formulation correct? Can this be further simplified?

Comment: Well $G \cup R = G$ so that's redundant.

Comment: Well, G = (G ∪ R) is simpler.  G=G is even simpler.  The equation you have is also correct, but what is the intent here?

Comment: The intent is to show the relation of G with R, D and U.

Comment: $R \subset G, G\cap D \ne \emptyset, G\cap U\ne \emptyset.$

Comment: Well, if you want to represent $G$ as the union of disjoint sets, $G=(G\cap D)\cup(G\cap U)\cup R\cup (G\smallsetminus (R\cup U\cup D))$ .

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I want to represent G as the union of disjoint sets D and U. What does (G∖(R∪U∪D) mean ?

Comment: $\setminus$ is the set minus operator.

Comment: Thanks everyone